# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 when running Lambda Test

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

running Lambda test with

```
{
  "var1": "2017-04-17T18:48:03.608Z",
  "var2": "0.45",
  "var3": "0.5"
}
```

Function:

```
exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {

    console.log("event.body = " + event.body);
    const {var1, var2, var3} = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const tmpItem = {
        "var_1": var1,
        "var_2": var2,
        "var_3": var3
    };
    console.log('Inserting item');
}
```

gives the following exception:

Request ID:
"3aa87175-d544-11e8-ab0a-2b268a563fb1"

Function Logs:

```
START RequestId: 3aa87175-d544-11e8-ab0a-2b268a563fb1 Version: $LATEST
2018-10-21T15:16:05.617Z    3aa87175-d544-11e8-ab0a-2b268a563fb1    event.body = undefined
2018-10-21T15:16:05.636Z    3aa87175-d544-11e8-ab0a-2b268a563fb1    SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:18:89)
END RequestId: 3aa87175-d544-11e8-ab0a-2b268a563fb1
REPORT RequestId: 3aa87175-d544-11e8-ab0a-2b268a563fb1  Duration: 82.98 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 25 MB  
RequestId: 3aa87175-d544-11e8-ab0a-2b268a563fb1 Process exited before completing request
```

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: What's the output for `event.body` ? Try to log it at the beginning.

Comment: Try without `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;`, I guess it has a bit different purpose than you wrote in the comment

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is because when you test your lambda with a packet, say

```
{
  "var1": "2017-04-17T18:48:03.608Z",
  "var2": "0.45",
  "var3": "0.5"
}
```

Then that packet is passed as the `event` to the handler.

However, you are doing `JSON.parse(event.body)`, but for the above packet, `event.body` is `undefined`(which has token `u` at position 0).

You should change your test packet to:

```
{
    "body": "{\"var1\":\"2017-04-17T18:48:03.608Z\",\"var2\":\"0.45\",\"var3\":\"0.5\"}"
}
```

Note that the body is a stringified JSON, because API Gateway Lambdas expect event body in a stringified format.

Comment: With your answer I'm getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1'

Comment: @user829174 Updated

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at your log message, you will see that `event.body = undefined`. If you try `JSON.parse(undefined)` in your console, you will be able to see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON` error.

In my case, I needed to configure by Gateway API in order to mock my response, thus this is what I did in my lambda function:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var testData = getTestData();
    callback(null, { "statusCode" : 200, "body" : JSON.stringify((testData))});
};

function getTestData() {
    var test= [ 
        {
            name: "Name1"
        },
        {
            name: "Name2"
        },
        {
            name: "Name3"
        }
        ];
    return test;
}
```

The above creates an endpoint which *spits* out the predefined mock response.

Answer (score 0):

The test is sent to Lamda as a JSON object, not as a string.

you should be able to access the elements as:

```
exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("event.body = " + event);
    //const {var1, var2, var3} = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const tmpItem = {
        "var_1": event.var1,
        "var_2": event.var2,
        "var_3": event.var3
    };
console.log('Inserting item');
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The reason maybe you don't use callback in your function. Try to add the following

```
var response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "x-custom-header" : "my custom header value"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(tmpItem)
};

// null is for error - means no error
// response object should be JSON.stringify compatible and has format described above.
callback(null, response);
```